# How add custom AcessResult reason?

Tags: 8, users

When i look at

> AccessResult::forbidden()

We can set a reason as parametter.

So i try this :

```
 public function access(Request $request, AccountInterface $account)
    {

        $userRole=$account->getRoles();

        if(in_array("administrator", $userRole) || in_array("agence", $userRole))
        {
            return AccessResult::allowed();
        }


        return AccessResult::forbidden('TESTTT');
    }
```

If a user try to access my page who call this custom check access, he got :

[image]

So it's in french but it's the default forbidden access message.
I try to custom this message, and i was thinking about the reason in parameter.

Any idea why i can't get TESTTT as message ?

Comment: The reason is for example use for REST requests, the UI doesn't really use them (yet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per function definition:

```
   /**
    * Creates an AccessResultInterface object with isForbidden() === TRUE.
    *
    * @param string|null $reason
    *   (optional) The reason why access is forbidden. Intended for developers,
    *   hence not translatable.
    *
    * @return \Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResultForbidden
    *   isForbidden() will be TRUE.
    */
   public static function forbidden($reason = NULL) {
     assert('is_string($reason) || is_null($reason)');
     return new AccessResultForbidden($reason);
   }
```

So the $reason is only intended for developers.